# Python Azure IoT SDK used on Azure Functions cannot write cert/key to local filesystem "Read only"

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-sdk

The Python Azure IoT Hub device SDK takes in a cert and key file for x509 certificates. I have an Azure Functions that was previously downloading these locally from Blob store and writing it to a file on the filesystem.

However my Functions started failing due to Azure changing their restrictions to the functions file system being "Read Only".

Is there a different way to

- do the device client connection without using x509 files
- is there a way to access a temp file system to write these files thru the Azure Functions?

```
        x509 = X509(
            cert_file = cert_file,
            key_file = key_file
        )
        device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_x509_certificate(
            hostname, 
            device_id, 
            x509
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Python function, the access to `\home\site\wwwroot` folder is ready only by default. You can use `\home` folder which is the parent folder of the code root folder instead.